# Could not display the received message

Tags: java, android, client

I'm trying to write some client application. I'm receiving a message but have troubles with displaying it. I'm newbie in android developing and this code is taken from the example. Sorry.

The MainActivity.

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    TextView textResponse;
    EditText editTextAddress, editTextPort;
    Button buttonConnect, buttonClear;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        editTextAddress = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.address);
        editTextPort = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.port);
        buttonConnect = (Button)findViewById(R.id.connect);
        buttonClear = (Button)findViewById(R.id.clear);
        textResponse = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.response);

        buttonConnect.setOnClickListener(buttonConnectOnClickListener);

        buttonClear.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                textResponse.setText("");
            }});
    }

    OnClickListener buttonConnectOnClickListener =
            new OnClickListener(){

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    MyClientTask myClientTask = new MyClientTask(
                            editTextAddress.getText().toString(),
                            Integer.parseInt(editTextPort.getText().toString()));
                    myClientTask.execute();
                }};

    public class MyClientTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        String dstAddress;
        int dstPort;
        String response = "";

        MyClientTask(String addr, int port){
            dstAddress = addr;
            dstPort = port;
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

            Socket socket = null;

            try {
                socket = new Socket(dstAddress, dstPort);

                ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream =
                        new ByteArrayOutputStream(1024);
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

                int bytesRead;
                InputStream inputStream = socket.getInputStream();

                /*
                 * notice:
                 * inputStream.read() will block if no data return
                 */
                while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1){
                    byteArrayOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                    response += byteArrayOutputStream.toString("UTF-8");
                }

            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                response = "UnknownHostException: " + e.toString();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                response = "IOException: " + e.toString();
            }finally{
                if(socket != null){
                    try {
                        socket.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            textResponse.setText(response);
            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }

    }

}
```

And there are a layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:autoLink="web"
        android:text="Client"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/address"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="dstAddress" />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/port"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="dstPort" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/connect"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Connect..."/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/clear"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Clear"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/response"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

UPD.

```
  public class MyClientTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

        String dstAddress;
        int dstPort;
        String response = "";

        MyClientTask(String addr, int port){
            dstAddress = addr;
            dstPort = port;
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

            Socket socket = null;

            try {
                socket = new Socket(dstAddress, dstPort);

                ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream =
                        new ByteArrayOutputStream(1024);
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

                int bytesRead;
                InputStream inputStream = socket.getInputStream();

                /*
                 * notice:
                 * inputStream.read() will block if no data return
                 */
                while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1){
                    byteArrayOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                    response += byteArrayOutputStream.toString("UTF-8");
                }

            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                response = "UnknownHostException: " + e.toString();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                response = "IOException: " + e.toString();
            }finally{
                if(socket != null){
                    try {
                        socket.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
            return response;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            textResponse.setText(response);
            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }

    }
```

Comment: You want to show the `response` in the TextView ?

Comment: @ShobhitPuri, my client is receiving messages -- i saw it in debuger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current source code, especially written `AsyncTask` is not good designated. Why you don't return response from `doInBackground()` method? You should follow officially written guidelines *"How to use AsyncTask"*.

So my opinion to you is to change your `doInBackground()` method signature - it should return your response as String and then in **onPostExecute()** method use this method's parameter to update UI.

Example:

```
public class MyClientTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

   ...

   @Override
   protected String doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
      ...
      return response;
   }

   @Override
   protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
      super.onPostExecute(result);
      textResponse.setText(result);
   }
}
```

Comment: I had done as you said. It's still not working. Maybe that is why my server sending messages every second ?
P.S. Sorry for latency -- bad connection  :(

Answer (score 0):

You return a Void on your onPostExecute method. That shouldn't be any valid information you need more exactly that cannot be a String you can display.